# How to get custom option price in cart in Magento 2

Tags: cart, price, custom-options, magento2.3.4, customizable-options

I have some customizable options in my products. I would like the checkout/cart page to show the individual prices of each option and not just the total price. Unfortunately I am missing any approach. Similar to the picture of a question from 6 years ago:
[image]

But I use Magento 2.3.4 and can't get the old code to work.

**Update/Edit 2:**

I have been able to collect quite a few things so far, but unfortunately I still cannot get the price. The price is 0.00 or is empty. What do I have to do to see the price of each option?
Here is my code, which gives me all options but not the prices:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Learning\Js\Block\CustomOption $block
 */

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(3);
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
$productTypeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
$productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
foreach($customOptions as $option) {
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { 
        continue;
    }

    foreach($values as $value) {
        echo $value->getTitle();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In overrided by your module file:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
```

add new method to get full product data by its id:

```
/**
 * Get item product
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function getProductFull($id)
{
   return $this->productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

Edit app/design/frontend/Module/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

At beginning add newly created function to get full product data for example:

```
//ChrisG added method in Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
$productFull = $this->getProductFull($product->getId());
```

and after line: ~48:

```
<dl class="item-options">
   <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
      <?php //ChrisG Add price to option

        $optionId = $_option['option_id'];
         $option = $productFull->getOptionById($optionId);
         $itemOption = $_item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
         $price = false;
         $optionPrice = "";
         if($_option['option_type'] != 'area') {
            foreach ($option->getValues() as $values) {
               if ($values->getId() == $itemOption['value']) {                         
                  $price = $values['price'];
               }
            }
            if ($price !== false && $price > 0) {
               $optionPrice = ", ". $this->convertPrice($price, true); 
            }
         } ?>
         <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd>
            <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
               <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] . $optionPrice; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
               <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span']) . $optionPrice; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php //ChrisG Add price to option ends ?>
                            
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Custom options are based on module:
itoris/dynamic-product-options

Tested on magento 2.3.2, good luck.